# Checking duplicate insertions in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

[MySQL output has duplicate inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqLEL.png)

I have a problem with MySQL where in duplicate inputs are being inserted to a table that I created, I implemented a Database in a WebApp using JSP and Servlets.

for example when I input the following in a form: 
Employee Name: Kylo Ren
Code: A
Sales: 3000

it yields into 3 different rows by only submitting the form once.

```
public void computeGross(Connection connection){

    switch(employeeCode){
    case "A":
        setGross(grossA+(getEmployeeSales()*grossSalesA));
        break;
    case "B":
        setGross(grossB+(getEmployeeSales()*grossSalesB));  
        break;
    case "C":
        setGross(grossC+(getEmployeeSales()*grossSalesC));  
        break;
    }   
    insertRecord(connection);
}

//compute for the commission, if sales>2500; commission=7.5% of sales
public void computeCommission(Connection connection){       

    if(employeeSales>2500)
        setCommission(getEmployeeSales()*commissionVal);
    else {
        setCommission(0);
    }

    insertRecord(connection);

}

//compute takehome pay, takehome pay = summation of gross and commission

public void computeTakeHomePay(Connection connection){


    setResult(getGross()+getCommission());

    insertRecord(connection);

}

private void insertRecord(Connection conn){

    try{
        String sql="insert into MachineProblem1(EmployeeName, EmployeeCode, EmployeeSales, EmployeeGross, EmployeeCommission, EmployeeResult)"+ "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement pstmnt= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmnt.setString(1, employeeName);
        pstmnt.setString(2, employeeCode);
        pstmnt.setDouble(3, employeeSales);
        pstmnt.setDouble(4, gross);
        pstmnt.setDouble(5, commission);
        pstmnt.setDouble(6, result);

        //now commit to database
        pstmnt.executeUpdate();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// get records

public ResultSet getAllRecords(Connection conn){
    ResultSet records = null;
    try{
        String sql="select*from MachineProblem1";

        PreparedStatement pstmnt= conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        records= pstmnt.executeQuery();


    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return records;
}
```

Comment: None of the records in the screenshot is a duplicate one. Pls clarify your question.

Comment: looks clean to me

Comment: What i meant is when i submitted a form like
 Employee Name: Kylo Ren 
Code: A
Sales: 3000

it always yields into three rows in the database table, like in the picture i only put Kylo Ren once but there are 3 different rows of Kylo Ren that comes out.

Comment: Those are 3 distinct rows. Look at the 3 money columns for Kylo Ren

Comment: So you need to log somewhere all the places you are making those calls and do better debugging. Everywhere you prep a call to `insert into MachineProblem1` log that fact to a text file with a timestamp. Those are not dupes and something is putting the varied moolah values in there

Comment: Yes but I only need to have the 3rd row where the inputs are complete, i have no idea why the first two row are appearing.

Comment: Either debug the code on the servlet side with writing out the info, or prove it to yourself by looking at the General Log on the mysql server side

Comment: The code in your question only contains the insert sql statement. It does not include the part where this insert is called, so we cannot possibly answer your question without you updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the result, You should remove the `insertRecord(connection)` method call from the computation methods and invoke`insertRecord(connection)`only after the computations are completed.

Alternatively, you can use an `Insert ... On Duplicate Update` SQL instead by checking if the key already exist.

[MySQL: INSERT ... On Duplicate Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

In `insertRecord` method, sql query is for insert, so everytime method called,it insert new record. 
=========================
Problem is in `insertRecord` method, you are calling `insertRecord` method from all the other three methods like `computeGross`, `computeTakeHomePay`, `computeCommission` and inside `insertRecord` method, problem is in this line:

```
String sql="insert into MachineProblem1(EmployeeName, EmployeeCode, EmployeeSales, EmployeeGross, EmployeeCommission, EmployeeResult)"+ "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

it insert three record in database, because it call this method body three time.

if you want  to resolve that, i'll suggest you that create one new method `updateRecord` in which you'll update the previously inserted record. 
and change in your code, whichever method you first call, it calls `insertRecord` method, while other methods call `updateRecord` method. so, the entry is not inserted three times, it update the previous entry only.